# Agregar motivo de cierre: El problema no puede ser reproducido o error tipográfico

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-completado, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Encontré esta pregunta: [Mi formulario de contacto me devuelve errores al enviar mensajes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4571/227)

La solución es la que indica @EduardoMunizaga en su comentario:

> (...) le falta un punto y coma (...)

Este tipo de preguntas no apoyan mucho a la comunidad puesto que son errores tipográficos, que suceden quizás por no dar una revisión detallada al código o a las configuraciones, tal como se explica en [esta publicación de Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252585/1065197).

Propongo que la opción de cierre que existe en el sitio en inglés también esté disponible en el sitio en inglés, ubicada dentro de **no relacionado porque**. Acá la imagen de la opción del sitio en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá la propuesta de traducción del texto:

> Esta pregunta fue ocasionada por un problema que **ya no se puede reproducir** o **por un simple error tipográfico**. Aunque las preguntas similares pueden estar relacionadas al sitio, esta pregunta fue resuelta de una manera que probablemente no ayude a los lectores futuros. Usualmente, esto puede evitarse al identificar y revisar de cerca el programa más corto y necesario para reproducir el problema antes de publicarlo.

¿Podría incluirse este tipo de cierre en el sitio en español?

Comment: **Debería** incluirse, problemas como estos ocurren muy seguido.

Comment: _Why isn't this code working_ también, es parte de educar a los nuevos. Si le cerramos la pregunta, viene al otro día y lee. demasiado amplio.. o se basa en opiniones y no se entiende bien el mensaje, cuando fue cerrada por cualquiera de estos dos motivos.

Comment: ¿_no se puede reproducir_ y _error tipográfico_ son lo suficientemente amplios y/o claros para votar por el cierre "o por la intervención de los moderadores" para preguntas que proveen código incompleto? He encontrado preguntas así...

Comment: @Mauricio si tienes una pregunta donde presentan un fragmento de código como: `int a = 5\r\n int b = 10;\r\n int c = a;\r\n /* más código acá */`, donde `\r\n` representa quiebre de línea y preguntan *por qué mi código no compila, he estado N horas y no doy con el problema*, entonces al ser la respuesta *te falta un ; en `int a=5;` . . . bueno . . .

Comment: La pregunta enlazada es interesante también porque OP la ha cambiado completamente. Haría un rollback, pero el usuario que contestó también actualizó su respuesta para que se ajustase a la modificación. Al menos ahora la nueva pregunta puede ser de más utilidad que la versión anterior (aunque sigo pensando que cambios así no se deberían hacer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta funcionalidad se ha agregado bajo el grupo de motivos de cierre **"no relacionado porque..."**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]