# Cómo mejorar el motivo de cierre "fuera de alcance"

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-de-cierre, motivos-de-cierre

Antes, los motivos de cierre como **no relacionado** eran:

[image: Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación...]

Y ahora:

[image: Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir...]

---

Me parece genial que hayan incorporado el motivo "*no se puede reproducir*" que había sido [pedido previamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/473/127).

Pero, ¿<strike>podemos volver</strike>  no les parece que necesitaríamos volver a tener el motivo de "*fuera del alcance*"?

De lo contrario, cualquier pregunta que no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con la temática del sitio no tendría un motivo de cierre, y me parece poco práctico tener que generar un motivo personalizado específicamente para cada uno de estos casos.

**¿Me ayudan a pensar cuál sería el mejor diseño para dejar *en espera* a este tipo de preguntas?**

Comment: Cambié la pregunta de [bug] a [discusión] en vista de las respuestas recibidas, ya que creo que hay muy buenas propuestas y es un punto a definir con la comunidad antes de solicitarlo.

Comment: ¿Alguien ve lo que escribo si elijo "otro"? Si es así, ¿Quiénes?

Comment: @ArtEze al emitir este tipo de votos, se genera automáticamente un comentario en la pregunta del tipo "*Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque <motivo>*". Además, cualquier usuario con 250 de reputación puede verlo haciendo click en `cerrar`, o si llega a la pregunta a través de [la cola de revisión de Votos de Cierre](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close)... Y, por otro lado, cualquiera puede ver [todas tus revisiones](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze?tab=activity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realmente la causa anterior era muy genérica e incluía todo: no relacionado significa que la pregunta no entra dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda. Y si te fijas, realmente no se ha eliminado, sólo  se ha "movido hacia arriba". Si ves la descripción de "No relacionado" es exactamente la misma descripción que se usaba para esa causa de cierre:

[image: Primer menú al cerrar]

Lo que se pide ahora es ser más específico con la causa de cierre, porque antes era un motivo bastante vago que tampoco ayudaba mucho al usuario al que se le cerraba la pregunta.

Lo que diría es que no necesitamos que vuelva el "fuera de alcance", eso ya lo tenemos cuando selecionamos "no relacionado porque..."; lo que haría falta es añadir más opciones dentro de esa sección (yo pondría las 3 que se describen como [no pertinentes incluso cuando tratan sobre programación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

> 1. Preguntas en busca de asistencia con la depuración ("¿por qué no
>      funciona este código?") deben incluir cual es el comportamiento
>      deseado, un problema o error específico y el mínimo de código
>      necesario para reproducirlo. Las preguntas sin una clara enunciación
>      del problema no son útiles para otros usuarios.
>      Ver: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
> 2. Preguntas acerca de *un problema que ya no puede ser reproducido o
>      que se debió a un simple error tipográfico*. Aunque preguntas
>      similares pueden ser pertinentes aquí, estas con frecuencia son
>      resueltas de forma tal que es poco probable sean de ayuda a otros
>      usuarios en el futuro. Esto puede ser muchas veces evitado al
>      identificar e inspeccionar con cuidado el [mínimo código necesario para
>      reproducir el problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) antes de publicar la pregunta.
> 3. Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del 
>      trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una 
>      descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Comment: "*añadir más opciones*" <-- Me parece una excelente propuesta y mucho más clara aún.

Comment: @Mariano Me parece bien que hayas puesto los 3 párrafos, incluso cuando la respuesta no lo incluía.

Answer (score 3):

### Suscribo la propuesta

Y hago una adenda: ampliar el alcance y **difundirlo en todo el sitio**:

Actualmente hay cuatro grandes temas en el alcance:

- un problema específico de programación, o
- un algoritmo de software, o
- herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
- un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

Pero dado que este es el único sitio en español en la red SE, está visto que no puede ser una copia fiel de SO por lo que ya [**se ha propuesto y votado**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio) una ampliación, **que debería hacerse válida y con máxima publicidad**, porque de hecho, ya están ocurriendo:

- Preguntas **conceptuales sobre el desarrollo de software (arquitectura, algoritmos, metodologías de desarrollo, ciencias de la computación, licencias de software...)** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).
- Preguntas sobre **administración y uso avanzado de bases de datos** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com).
- Preguntas que solicitan **revisiones de código en busca de posibles problemas o sugerencias de mejora** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Estos tres tiene más de 10 votos, pero hay otros tres temas con votos positivos.

Comment: Yo creo que deberíamos aceptar esos 3 del segundo grupo que tienen votos positivos. Los demás también se ven interesantes pero sería necesario ver que realmente haya apoyo de la gente

Comment: Concuerdo totalmente con que hay que revisar los motivos de cierre @toledano, y quizás mejorar la descripción de [help/on-topic]. Me pregunto si no sería mejor abrir una nueva publicación para eso. De esa forma dejaríamos esta simplemente para agregar el motivo, y en la otra hablaríamos de "*qué está dentro del alcance*".

Comment: @toledano Edité la pregunta en función de las respuestas recibidas para abrir el tema a discusión.