# ¿Podemos añadir una razón de cierre expresamente para las preguntas que buscan recursos (librerías, tutoriales)?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, motivos-de-cierre

Las clásicas preguntas del tipo

> ¿Podéis aconsejarme una página/tutorial/librería para aprender/resolver *X*?

suelen cerrarse como "basadas en opiniones". Y en cierto modo es verdad, se me ocurren pocos casos en los que no haya muchas respuestas válidas pero todas basadas en gustos personales.

Pero no podemos asegurar que SIEMPRE sea así, y además:

- [so] ya tiene una respuesta específica para la petición de recursos externos:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

- Podríamos añadir a las razones, por dar consistencia, las mismas que cuando pedimos borrar una respuesta con exclusivamente una URL: Los enlaces pueden romperse o quedar desfasados (versiones nuevas de librerías, aparición de otras, abandono de la comunidad de librerías antiguas...). Y, si lo pensamos un momento, una pregunta que se responde con una URL es precisamente lo que busca: una respuesta que no es válida.

Comment: como.. esta pregunta no incluye la traduccion del motivo ;)???

Comment: Relacionada: [Cómo mejorar el motivo de cierre “fuera de alcance”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/905/127)

Comment: Según [el comentario de JuanM](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2930/a%c3%b1adamos-la-opci%c3%b3n-pregunta-sin-un-planteamiento-claro-del-problema-en-las-raz#comment10207_2930), sólo se permiten 3 motivos, por eso dejamos de proponer la mejora de los motivos de cierre... Pero viendo los motivos de otros sitios, creo que habría que repreguntar esto.

Comment: @Mariano exacto. Por lo que veo, en [pt.so] también hay 3 motivos, no más. Probablemente sea solamente [so] la que tenga 5. Como moderador de un sitio beta, puedo confirmar que en nuestro caso ([spanish.se]) apenas podemos añadir tres.

Comment: @mariano cuando se creó el nuevo reporte de necesidad de depuración de código, se juntaron las de no reproducible y error tipográfico de nuevo en una.

Comment: @lois6b claro, es el link que puse del comentario de Juan, diciendo que sólo permite 3... después me confundí con SOpt, me hice un lío porque todavía no tengo el privilegio para cerrar, y me olvidé que con *reportar* aparece uno diferente (acá también).... en fin, no hay que repreguntar nada, tenés razón.

Comment: Yo por mi parte estoy totalmente de acuerdo en que encajaría mejor algo similar al inglés, pero como bien dice @Mariano parece que no es posible añadir nuevas razones. Tal vez podriamos "llorar" un poco a Stack Exchange para que nos den la opción de tener las mismas razones de cierre que Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @Pikoh lo único que encontré hasta ahora: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242247/are-there-close-reasons-that-appear-only-for-questions-with-specific-tags/242248#comment792133_242248

Comment: @Mariano bueno, quien hace ese comentario no es moderador (edito, si lo es en Manga y Anime parece ser), y la unica razón que pone es que Stack Overflow tiene 5. No es muy fiable

Comment: @Mariano eso es lo que yo decía. Tal vez si Juan o tal vez algun moderador solicita que aqui necesitamos mas razones de cierre, vendiéndolo como que el sitio crece y bla bla bla, sea posible que nos activen de alguna manera esa opción. Por pedir que no quede

Comment: @Pikoh ahora solo falta una >>>**buena**<<< publicación que logre consenso de la comunidad, tenga una buena redacción de los motivos de cierre y explique por qué son necesarios más (-yo no me ofrezco ni loco a hacerlo})

Comment: @Mariano Yo creo que esa sería una labor de Juan, que puede conocer mejor que teclas tocar para llegar al corazoncito de Stack Exchange :)

Comment: Pues parece que [ya lo tenemos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4708/83)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por otro lado, [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) también se ha mostrado dispuesto a añadir otra razón de cierre a la parte de "No relacionado porque.." con lo que se puede añadir la razón que originó esta pregunta si hay consenso en ello.

Comment: Sería buena opción. En SO existe y funciona bien, con un 5% de los cierres totales (fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats)

Comment: @fedorqui lo cual no es óbice, cortapisa ni valladar para implementar en algún sitio una publicación con recursos como propone Pablo y nos sugirió Nicolas

Comment: Para nada, no hay estorbo, impedimento, inconveniente, traba, obstáculo, dificultad ni rémora para implementar eso.

Comment: pues se hizo, realizó, ejecutó

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' efectivamente, se produjo, compuso, confeccionó y manufacturó (que grande tu comentario ;)

Answer (score 3):

El usuario/moderador/empleado de SO.ru [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) nos comentó en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47023361#47023361) que en SO.ru existe una [pregunta *wiki*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) creada para crear colecciones de tutoriales y manuales más o menos *atemporales* (las bases de los lenguajes de programación no suelen variar con el tiempo)

Creo que podría ser una buena solución, manteniendo limpio el sitio pero a la vez siendo útil al usuario (un win-win, como comenta [@lois6b](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47023702#47023702))

Comment: En Spanish.SE tenemos una, igual que en muchos otros sitios de idiomas: [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674). Idealmente esto se debería poner en la wiki de etiqueta, pero tiene mucha menos visibilidad, así que una pregunta de este tipo parece muy útil. Lo que suele haber es discrepancia sobre si debe estar en Meta o en el sitio principal. Nosotros en Spanish.SE optamos por el sitio principal.

Comment: @fedorqui Meta es para preguntas sobre SOes, no sobre programación. Creo que tiene más sentido ponerla allí porque además saldría en el buscador

Comment: @PabloLozano no ha dicho meta, sino en el wiki de la etiqueta. En realidad, a mi me parece una mejor idea todavía ya que así estaría muy bien categorizado, aunque se pierde visibilidad por un lado, y por otro el proceso de edición es mas restringido.

Comment: @PabloLozano como dije antes, hay discrepancia sobre dónde ponerlo. Si te interesa el debate, en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2742/1674) resumí qué ha hecho cada sitio de idiomas.  Lo bueno de ponerlo en el sitio principal es que puede funcionar como pregunta canónica a la cual marcar el resto como preguntas duplicadas. En mi opinión, lo bueno de ponerlo en Meta es que se redunda en el hecho de que no es _on topic_ en el sitio y no transmite el mensaje de que sí. Dicho lo cual, el buscador también indexa Meta.

Comment: Acá tenemos algo así en Meta. [Propuesta: Lista de libros de C++ en la etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1811/65) Tal vez valdría revisitar esa propuesta y tomarla en cuenta para lo que se determine hacer ahora.