# Modificar el texto del motivo de cierre "basado en opiniones" para incluir las preguntas que buscan enlaces externos

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Uno de los motivos de cierre de las preguntas es:

> Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica.

Supongo que por motivos varios (no se pueden añadir fácilmente más razones de cierre, similitud con SO en inglés...) se ha considerado que las preguntas en las que se piden librerías, cursos... etc se han de cerrar con este motivo, pero creo que no queda claro y he visto a varios usuarios quejándose de que el motivo de cierre de su pregunta es incorrecto.

Por ejemplo, si pido "la mejor librería" para realizar una tarea, claramente es una pregunta subjetiva, pero si pido la librería "más usada" puede no ser tan subjetiva. Por ejemplo, la librería más usada en Java para ORM es *Hibernate*, en Javascript lo más usado sigue siendo *jQuery*... o si pido un enlace de descarga de cierta herramienta (un IDE, una librería), un enlace al sitio oficial es claramente no basado en opiniones, sólo hay una respuesta posible. El problema es que ese hecho puede quedar anticuado en meses o años o los enlaces pueden apuntar a versiones antiguas.

¿Deberíamos modificar este motivo de cierre?

Ejemplo de pregunta cerrada que creo que no es un tema de opiniones: [¿Alguien me dice donde puedo descargar SQL server con agent service?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267080/alguien-me-dice-donde-puedo-descargar-sql-server-con-agent-service)

Propuesta:

> Esta pregunta está pidiendo respuestas que estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica o bien pide enlaces externos que pueden quedar desactualizados o rotos.

PD: No me gusta lo poco que se remarcan las citas con los nuevos estilos :P

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo. En cuanto a lo de las citas...https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/ y https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/

Comment: Aun que sea offtopic, hay un hilo en meta pidiendo que se vuelvan a poner las citas en amarillo [Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/please-revert-the-quote-background-from-white-to-yellow).

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que Stack Overflow en inglés tiene dos opciones para esto:

- Basado en opiniones, motivo de cierre de primer nivel:

  > **Opinion-based**
  > Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
- Off-topic because... con la subcategoría siguiente consistente en que *se busca recomendación de libros, librerías u otros elementos externos al sitio*:

  > **It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources**. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Nosotros solamente tenemos la primera y la usamos para lo que afecta a la segunda. Podemos *retorcer* el texto e ir ampliando, pero ¿y si se añadiera la segunda también? Creo que la configuración actual del sitio no lo permite, pero ya va siendo buena hora de que nos dejen.

Nótese que esto ya se discutió en [¿Podemos añadir una razón de cierre expresamente para las preguntas que buscan recursos (librerías, tutoriales)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3191/83).

Comment: "Opinion-based" no debería tener una traducción literal. En mi opinión, sería mejor: "Solicita opiniones y/o recomendaciones" y caben las dos opciones.

Comment: @toledano sí bueno, pero considero que sería interesante tener más opciones de cierre para poder ser más específico