# Solicitud para tener 5 razones de cierre personalizadas en lugar de las 3 disponibles actualmente

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Quiero recuperar una vieja reivindicación del sitio: poder añadir mas razones de cierre específicas del sitio.

Actualmente, en Stack Overflow en español, contamos con 3 razones de cierre personalizadas. Estas son:

- Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.
- Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable
- La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Creo que nos beneficiaríamos de poder añadir alguna razón más. En concreto, yo siempre he echado en falta el cierre específico para preguntas que piden recomendaciones de librerias, tutoriales, etc.. Esto es algo que ya se ha solicitado en el pasado, por ejemplo:

- [Modificar el texto del motivo de cierre "basado en opiniones" para incluir las preguntas que buscan enlaces externos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4643/15301)
- [¿Podemos añadir una razón de cierre expresamente para las preguntas que buscan recursos (librerías, tutoriales)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3191/15301)

He querido añadir esta pregunta para, si hay consenso, solicitar que nos aumenten las razones de cierre personalizadas de 3 a 5. Si es así, añadiré la etiqueta [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) ([estado-en-revisión](/questions/tagged/estado-en-revisi%c3%b3n)) que debería hacer que esta solicitud llegue a los CM, y espero que por fin podamos tener esta opción disponible.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. Creo que actualmente [so] es el único sitio con cinco opciones, ninguno de los SOint lo tiene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aumentó el número de ranuras por razones personalizadas de cierre a 4. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Entiendo que ahora los moderadores son los que deben añadir el motivo

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' asi es. Pensaba añadir una publicación aqui para que podamos acordar la mejor redacción de esa nueva razón de cierre. Que te parece?

Comment: Muy útil, por mí adelante con ella @Pikoh