# Nueva razón de cierre personalizada

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, motivos-de-cierre

Hoy tenemos una buena noticia. Tras varios años solicitándolo, hemos conseguido que al sitio se le conceda un nuevo motivo de cierre de preguntas personalizado (thanks Nicholas!). En esta publicación podéis leer la solicitud, con enlaces a un par de publicaciones previas sobre el tema: [Solicitud para tener 5 razones de cierre personalizadas en lugar de las 3 disponibles actualmente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4681/15301)

La idea es que esa nueva razón se utilice para el cierre de preguntas que solicitan librerías o recursos externos, una razón que hace años existe en [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente, esas preguntas en el sitio se cierran como basadas en opiniones, lo que a mi entender no era muy acertado.

En esta publicación la idea es alcanzar un consenso sobre la redacción de esta nueva razón de cierre personalizada. Yo voy a añadir una (básicamente, una traducción del texto de Stack Overflow) y podéis votar por ella, sugerir modificaciones a esta, o añadir otra respuesta con vuestras sugerencias.

---

(Editado)

La nueva razón ya está disponible para que todos podamos usarla! Aqui os comparto una captura de como se ve la nueva razón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mirando en las [Estadísticas de Razones de cierre específicas de la comunidad presentes y pasadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) veo que con mucha frecuencia se usa un motivo personalizado del tipo _no versa sobre alguna duda de programación_. No sé si debería atajarse también, ya sea definiendo este como concepto o reescribiendo alguno de los actuales para que encaje allí

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' por el momento contamos con 4 razones personalizadas, pero podemos aprovechar también para redefinir el texto de las 3 existentes hasta ahora si lo consideramos necesario. Si tienes alguna sugerencia, será bienvenida.

Comment: falta un espacio entre la coma y _herramientas_ y _librerías_. No sé si es porque os faltaba espacio

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' efectivamente. Si ponía los espacios se pasaba de los caracteres permitidos, asi que tuve que elegir :)

Comment: Ah vale. En el Teams de Mods había un hilo de Glorfindel con truquillos para ganar caracteres. Cosas como poner `/q/1234` en lugar de la dirección completa y un largo etcétera. En este caso no veo nada recortable, pero para un futuro.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Lo primero que pensé fue volver a mi idea original _Buscando recomendaciones de libros..._ pero creo que está mas claro como está, a pesar de que los que tenemos toc con esas cosas estemos un poco incomodos ;)

Comment: Ya te digo, yo tengo que poner la mano encima de la pantalla cada vez que lo veo :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías de software u otros recursos externos
>
> <sub>Estas preguntas tienden a recibir respuestas basadas en opiniones</sub>

Comment: Si eso diría _La pregunta está buscando..._ y luego esa coma antes de "u" me parece muy Oxford, en castellano no la pondría

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si, mis estudios en Oxford me marcaron mucho ;) Estuve dudando la verdad, ahora mismo no se si la rae tiene alguna recomendación sobre el particular.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' tienes razón como siempre: https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma punto 1.2.1

Comment: Jajaja es por la [Oxford comma](https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma) que generalmente usan en el inglés británico

Comment: Añado: sería bueno que el texto enlace a algún punto del centro de ayuda o de meta con explicación de qué es una pregunta de recomendación. Un buen ejemplo es esta de MetaSO: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' me parece una muy buena idea. Si en algun momento encuentro tiempo trataré de traducir esa pregunta

Comment: Tú, yo u otra persona, que estás haciendo mucho tú! Me sorprende que no haya ningún otro moderador (ni usuario en general) comentando en esto. ¿No se supone que es precisamente para estas cosas que están los moderadores?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' me gustaría poder hacer mas, pero el trabajo es lo primero ya sabes :). En cuanto al resto de los moderadores, todos tenemos circunstancias personales, hay que entenderlo

Comment: Claro, todos estamos en el mismo barco: trabajando y aportando aquí cuando tenemos un momento. A lo que me refiero (y estoy abriendo otro melón) es que los moderadores tenéis herramientas más extensas para analizar el estado de la comunidad y los problemas que afrontar. Me sorprende que casi todos estén más centrados en tareas de usuarios 10 K (comentario, edición, recepción de usuarios...)

Answer (score -3):

Voy a poner otra traducción. Aunque la propuesta de @Pikoh me parece suficiente, pienso que la pregunta no busca nada, es el usuario que lo pide (mediante una pregunta, claro.)

Así que me inclino por algo así.

> El usuario pretende recibir recomendaciones de libros, herramientas,
>   librerías de software u otros recursos externos

Comment: Estoy buscando referencias, pero estoy casi seguro de que "la pregunta busca" es gramáticalmente correcta en castellano. A mi me parece además más adecuada dado que asi incides en la pregunta en concreto, y no en el usuario que puede tomarselo como algo personal. De todas maneras, muchas gracias por molestarte en sugerir :)

Comment: Interesante... en Stack Overflow siempre se dice que el centro de todo es la publicación, no el usuario. Votamos publicaciones, no personas; recompensamos publicaciones, no personas. Por eso, me parece que decir _el usuario..._ puede parecer una crítica a la persona y no a la publicación. ¿Y _En esta pregunta, el usuario..._?