# ¿Estaría bien separar en dos el motivo de cierre "Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico"?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

¿Estaría bien separar el siguiente motivo de cierre en dos?

Pasar de esto:

> Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico.

A esto:

> - Este problema no se puede reproducir.
> - Este problema contiene un error tipográfico.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/473/65

Comment: @fedorqui Error mío, no está implementado, voy a poner como correcta la de Luiggi.

Comment: (Me pillas en línea) ¡Gracias! Si quieres que abramos una pregunta aparte para solicitar lo otro, dinos :) Borro el anterior comentario y borra este si quieres cuando lo leas.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, puedes hacer la pregunta. Tiene que tratar sobre las descripciones pero por separado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voto por separar el motivo de cierre

Comment: considero que tendría mayor orden. Saludos :D

Answer (score 3):

Voto por mantener el motivo de cierre unificado

Comment: HAHAH no entiendo por que hay voto negativo en esta publicacion. es una votacion separada en dos respuestas.

Comment: @lois6b hay gente que simplemente no sabe leer =\

Answer (score 2):

> Lo pongo como respuesta en lugar de comentario a [una de las otras](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2038/65) respuestas por el formato

En [Agregar motivo de cierre: El problema no puede ser reproducido o error tipográfico](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/473/65) se sugirió agregar una descripción más completa que la actual. En aquel hilo no se explica el motivo por el cual no se incluyó la redacción completa, pero sea cual fuera la razón, ahora las condiciones son otras

La propuesta original fue una traducción del tipo de no relacionado que está en la versión en inglés (modifiqué el énfasis):

> Esta pregunta fue ocasionada por un problema que *ya no se puede reproducir* o *por un simple error tipográfico*. Aunque las preguntas similares pueden estar relacionadas al sitio, esta pregunta **fue resuelta de una manera que probablemente no ayude a los lectores futuros**. Usualmente, esto puede evitarse al identificar y revisar de cerca el programa más corto y necesario para reproducir el problema antes de publicarlo.

Considero que parte relevante es lo que he puesto en negritas, que dicho de otra forma es que las soluciones tienen que ser de utilidad a lectores futuros.

Comment: ¡Muy bien expuesto!

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que se está votando por separar, y que esta respuesta también está siendo votada, creo que convendría pensar en motivos más descriptivos por separado

Comment: @Mariano: Luego de mi publicación me di cuenta que los motivos ya estaban separados, así que yo creo que habría que dar por concluída esta votación y quizás abordar el tema de motivos de cierre - no relacionado en otro hilo partiendo de clarificación de la temática del sitio.

Comment: Sí, lo comenté en la pregunta con ArtEze y sugiere crear una pregunta aparte para solicitar esta útil propuesta tuya.