# Añadamos la opción "pregunta sin un planteamiento claro del problema" en las razones de cierre como "No relacionado"

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-completado, motivos-de-cierre

Me gustaría proponer añadir al menos una nueva razón de cierre entre las opciones de "No relacionado".

En Stack Overflow en inglés disponemos de la siguiente:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Traducido:

> Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración (**¿por qué no funciona este código?**) deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo **en la propia pregunta**. Las preguntas sin **un planteamiento claro del problema** no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Actualmente, cuando me encuentro con casos así normalmente la única opción que se ajusta un poco es *no está claro lo que se pregunta*, pero considero interesante remarcar al autor de preguntas similares que el problema es específicamente que no basta con soltar tu código y decir que no funciona, sino que se espera una descripción detallada tanto del problema como del comportamiento esperado.

Es cierto que ahora contamos con opciones para aclarar esto enlazando a alguna de las respuestas de [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/), pero considero que tener esa razón de cierre específica sería útil tanto al que ve como su pregunta es cerrada, como para el sitio.

¿Qué os parece?

Comment: Muy a favor de esta propuesta, yo suelo elegir "demasiado amplia" pero desde luego tampoco es exactamente lo que quiero decir. "Talk is cheap, show me the code", como diría Linus

Comment: Solo para aclarar, ¿estás proponiendo agregar esta opción bajo la sección `No relacionado` de los motivos de cierre, o en la sección principal de motivos de cierre? Porque cuando alguien no provee un [mcve], no considero que la pregunta *no sea relacionada*. Pero sí estoy de acuerdo que es motivo de cierre.

Comment: @sstan Me remito al comentario de lois6b a la respuesta de Jose Antonio. Aunque para mi sería mejor como razón principal,me temo que la opción disponible debe ser bajo _no relacionado_

Comment: @Pikoh: Ah entiendo. Gracias. Me parece muy buena la propuesta entonces.

Comment: cuándo se da por zanjado un tema asi?

Comment: @lois6b pues no se...tal vez debas consultarlo con otros moderadores o con JuanM...

Comment: Se ha agregado esta razón ya.

Comment: @JuanM pues muchas gracias ;)

Comment: @Juan M: Muchas gracias. Noto que el texto de la nueva razón de cierre es: "Pregunta sin un planteamiento claro del problema." ¿Será posible ampliar el texto un poco más para que se aproxime al que propone Pikoh en la pregunta? Por lo menos para que inluya un enlace a [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Digo esto porque, sin los detalles adicionales, no estoy seguro que el que pregunta sabrá qué hacer para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: @sstan me parece excelente, dame un rato y lo cambio :)

Comment: @JuanM no se agrego, se cambio por la de cierre por error tipografico.. y en mi opinion no quedo bien. ahora en español cual es la diferencia entre no esta claro lo que se pregunta  y Pregunta sin un planteamiento claro del problema?? No es lo mismo? para mi, la embarraron... ahora cuando una pregunta es confusa, cual de los dos motivos debo usar?

Comment: @JuanM: Veo que ahora quedó mas completo el mensaje, gracias. Pero en parte lo que dice gbianchi sigue siendo cierto. Porque ahora desapareció el cierre por error tipografico, que sigue siendo una razón de cierre que necesitamos.

Comment: @sstan lo que no pude revisar hasta no hacer este cambio es que se permiten solamente 3 razones de cierre adicionales. Al agregar esta, tuve que quitar otra. Decidí intercambiarla con la de los errores tipográficos.

Comment: @JuanM: Ah, pensaba que se podía basándome en lo que veo en la versión inglesa del sitio. Pero si tuviera que escoger, yo guardaría el del error tipográfico y mas bien combinaría la razón de cierre *"Este problema no se puede reproducir."* con esta nueva razón de cierre, porque son muy relacionados. Pero a ver que opinan los demás.

Comment: El "error tipografico" siempre se puede poner como "otro" en mi opinion. Pero si, a ver que opinan los demas @sstan

Comment: @sstan de hecho antes estaban juntas y [se decidió separarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2036/83). Dada la situación actual, probablemente lo más fácil (a la espera de mayor debate) sea restablecer temporalmente el motivo _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico_.

Comment: @lois6b nótese por cierto que esto lo podéis modificar los moderadores.

Comment: @fedorqui: Tu propuesta me parece muy bien dado las circunstancias.

Comment: ¡Listo ya! Espero y quede todo de buena forma.

Comment: @JuanM: ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 11):

Estoy a favor de esta propuesta.

Con demasiada frecuencia me encuentro con "demasiado amplio" como motivo de cierre de una pregunta que no es demasiado amplia. La puesta en espera (idealmente de forma provisional) de una pregunta debe servir para ayudar a quien la hace a mejorarla. Y dar un motivo de cierre erróneo va en contra de esto.

No podemos añadir todos los motivos de cierre porque entonces la interfaz de cierre perdería usabilidad. Pero sí es recomendable hacerlo en aquellos casos que son frecuentes. Como pienso que es este.

Comment: Si podemos crear/editar motivos de cierre pero solo los recogidos en "No relacionado" que es lo que pide Pikoh. Si fuera otra categoria tendriamos que contactar con los desarrolladores pero no me suena ningun sitio de la red con otros cierres personalizados fuera de No relacionado, por lo que no nos harian mucho caso xD